# How to fill missing and adjust irregular time intervals in a data.frame in R

Tags: r, date

I have several datasets mostly with 15 min intervals of time. However, some datasets have missing readings (e.g., 3rd row in sample dataset was supposed to be "May 1 2015 00:40AM". In addition, there are some timesteps that are longer than 15 min (e.g., see 3rd and 6th rows)
How can add the missing time steps so that my Date will continue with 15 min intervals and at the same time adjust those time steps with more than 15 min intervals to 15 min?

```
s <- data.frame(Date = c(
                       "May 1 2015 00:10AM","May 1 2015 00:25AM",
                       "May 1 2015 00:56AM","May 1 2015 01:10AM",
                       "May 1 2015 01:25AM","May 1 2015 01:41AM",
                       "May 1 2015 01:55AM"),
                        val = c(1:7)
                 )
```

My desired output would be the following:

```
> s
                Date val
1 May 1 2015 00:10AM   1
2 May 1 2015 00:25AM   2
3 May 1 2015 00:40AM  NA
4 May 1 2015 00:55AM   3
5 May 1 2015 01:10AM   4
6 May 1 2015 01:25AM   5
7 May 1 2015 01:40AM   6
8 May 1 2015 01:55AM   7
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your final desired data.frame?

Comment: sorry for the format but I need something like this:                                 
 s <- data.frame(Date = c(
  "May 1 2015 00:10AM","May 1 2015 00:25AM","May 1 2015 00:40AM","May 1 2015 00:55AM","May 1 2015 01:10AM","May 1 2015 01:25AM","May 1 2015 01:40AM", "May 1 2015 01:55AM"), val = c(1,2,NA,3,4,5,6,7)
)

Comment: Please put the desired output in the question, not in comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

First, turn your `s` dataframe variable "Date" into POSIXct, so you can work with it:

```
s <- data.frame(Date = c(
  "May 1 2015 00:10AM","May 1 2015 00:25AM",
  "May 1 2015 00:56AM","May 1 2015 01:10AM",
  "May 1 2015 01:25AM","May 1 2015 01:41AM",
  "May 1 2015 01:55AM"),
  val = c(1:7)
) %>% dplyr::mutate(Date = lubridate::parse_date_time(Date, "b d Y HM"))
```

Second, you can join this with another data frame that has *all* the time intervals you are expecting. First, we construct it, using a difference of time intervals (15 mins in this case):

```
one <- lubridate::parse_date_time("May 1 2015 00:10AM", orders = "b d Y HM")
two <- lubridate::parse_date_time("May 1 2015 00:25AM", orders = "b d Y HM")
dif <- two - one
```

Now the dataframe:

```
other_df <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(from = lubridate::parse_date_time("May 1 2015 00:10AM", 
                                        orders = "b d Y HM"), 
      to = lubridate::parse_date_time("May 1 2015 01:55AM", 
                                      orders = "b d Y HM"), 
      by = dif))
```

Join the two:

```
result <- dplyr::full_join(other_df, s)

> result
                  Date val
1  2015-05-01 00:10:00   1
2  2015-05-01 00:25:00   2
3  2015-05-01 00:40:00  NA
4  2015-05-01 00:55:00  NA
5  2015-05-01 01:10:00   4
6  2015-05-01 01:25:00   5
7  2015-05-01 01:40:00  NA
8  2015-05-01 01:55:00   7
9  2015-05-01 00:56:00   3
10 2015-05-01 01:41:00   6
```

Comment: I had a very similar idea using `base` coding, so glad we were on the same page. However, the final output includes additional rows and `NA`s because of the time intervals that are one or two minutes offset of the original `s` data.frame (e.g., `2015-05-01 01:41:00` vs. `2015-05-01 01:40:00`).

Comment: The problem I still have is how to adjust time intervals that are offset by a minute so that everything will be 15 min interval

Comment: You can do this using the `floor_date` function in `lubridate` and adding ten minutes to each time. For instance, `s$Date<-lubridate::floor_date(s$Date,"15 minutes")+(60*10)` will generate the 15 minute intervals you want while retaining the `val` column intact

Comment: When I run your code, I get the error: Error in match.arg(unit) : 
  'arg' should be one of “second”, “minute”, “hour”, “day”, “week”, “month”, “year”, “quarter”